# how TO know if user clicks/hovers div on my site using Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

how can i know if user clicks/hovers div on my site ?

i am a little confuse Whether to use goal or to use

events.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could do both!  Use a jQuery mouseover / click event handler to pass two separate goals and then create a "Goal Based Event"

If you'd like to know "how many times did this happen?" use an event (total = # of times; unique = # of visits who did it)

if it's something you'd like a "how many visits did this happen in?" use goals.

Goals provide a bit better reporting for cost breakdowns -- e.x.: "How much did I spend to get a visit to click a div?" is easier answered with a goal than an event.